# adding a different sized label within h1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a label, but I personally thing the default label is ugly. If you just do:

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h1>
```

Then the label looks huge, and the bottom of the label goes below the "g" in heading. Let me elaborate on what I mean by that, "headin" have the bottoms equal, then "g"'s bottom is below that of a normal letter (like y,j,etc) and the bottom of the label goes even below that. If you still don't know what I mean look at the example on Bootstrap's site.

Anyways what I want to do is have a smaller label, like the size you get with h3 for example, and have that label's top be aligned with the top of the text. Again let me explain, EAYlkt (well not in Stackoverflow's text) have the same "top" like I was saying with "headin"'s bottom. So I want to have a smaller label that's inline with the top, kinda like a superscript, OR be aligned with the "headin" bottom.

I kinda get what I want with the following:

```
<h1>Heading</h1><h3><span class="label label-default">New</span></h3>

in .css
.jumbotron h1, h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but the bottom of label is aligned with the bottom of the "g", which is the one way I don't want. If this was confusing give me a comment and I'll try to elaborate or send you a link, but hopefully I made my point. So what can I do to get my desired effect? I apologize if this is trivial, but I've only just started learning about making webpages

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to start off with some perhaps unconventional, but warranted advice. Feel free to ignore this advice, but I think it will benefit you.

If you are just getting started with web development, and you want to learn web development, don't use frameworks like Bootstrap. These frameworks are intended to be deployed by people who understand the languages underneath, and that can solve simple problems like this because they have the experience of working with those languages. You won't really be learning web development (proper HTML structure, CSS, etc.) by using Bootstrap, you'll just be learning Bootstrap.

Evidence of this can be seen immediately in your use of an `h3` element directly after an `h1` element. Read more about proper heading use [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements).

---

On to the problem.

[CSS verticle-align property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

You can use this property to vertically align an inline element inside its parent.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ap88q2g/)

Code:

HTML

```
<h1>Hello<span class="subtitle">This is my subtitle</span></h1>
```

CSS

```
.subtitle {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: I was using h3 directly after like that because the bootstrap Label changes size based on which tag its in, so a Label inside h1 will be bigger than one inside h3, I wanted a smaller overall Label so I put it inside h1, and since my jumbotron only contained and h1 and h3 in those places, I set them to be inline in css so they would be next to each other. Basically I was hacking at the code to try and get a desired result. And to your overall point, yes I am aware, this is the only project I am using Bootstrap for, and I know I still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Bootstrap does not have support for label size classes.

There are 2 options.
First, you can wrap the span tag in different header sizes (h1,h2,h3,h4). 
Second, create a custom class for label, and custom CSS code for that label.

> ### 1st option: Change Header Size
>
> **Note:**`<h1>` creates a larger label than `<h6>`
>
> `<h1>Heading<span class="label label-danger label-sm">Hot</span></h1>`
>
> `<h5>Heading<span class="label label-danger label-sm">Hot</span></h5>`
>
> ### 2nd Option: Add Class to Span + CSS Styling
>
> 1. Add class="label-sm" to `<span>` in HTML file.
> 2. Create CSS styling for span.label-sm
>
> ### 1. Add .label-sm to span
>
> `<span class="label label-danger label-sm">Hot</span>`
>
> ### 2. Create CSS styling for span.label-sm
>
> `span.label-sm {font-size:10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not address the OP's issues with a label's vertical alignment in bootstrap, it's worth mentioning that in bootstrap, you can "create lighter, secondary text in any heading with a generic `<small>` tag or the .small class" (see [CSS Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)).

If you put your label within the 'small' tags, it will also be smaller and lighter.

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h1>
<h1>Example heading <small><span class="label label-default">New</span></small></h1>
```